# Не проходит последняя итерация цикла в VBA

Tags: visual-basic, vba

Пишу на vba простейший цикл - проход икса по сегменту [a, b], параллельно что-то вычисляя. Когда икс дойдет до b, цикл останавливается. Простейший пример:

```
a = 3
b = 4
h = 0.1
x = a

Cells(5, 1).Value = "x:"
Cells(6, 1).Value = "y:"
Do While x <= b
    ... тут всякие вычисления ...
    x = x + h
Loop
```

При проходе через Debugger, когда x = 4, он сравнивается с b, которое также равно 4, но при этом в тело цикла не идет и выходит, хотя там явно стоит **x <= b**.

В чём может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Т.к. в Вашем случае `x` имеет тип `Double`, то и `b` приводится к этому же типу. А сравнение чисел с плавающей точкой - больная тема для большинства языков программирования. Попробуйте в операторе сравнения либо сравнивать разность с определённой величиной (погрешностью), либо округлять оба числа в операторе сравнения до нужной точности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, что проблема в том, что `x` - число с плавающей запятой после того, как его сложили `h`.  Соответственно, на каждую итерацию цикла оно будет накапливать некоторую погрешность от сложения с `h`.
В итоге получится, что оно равно не `4`, а `4.0000000000001` (к примеру), что больше `b`.
Попробуйте

```
epsilon = h/2
...
Do While x - epsilon <= b
```

Comment: Да, точно. Debugger показывал, что `x = 4`, `b = 4` и я совершенно забыть про погрешность, спасибо)